# Multiple Windows10 installations - is it possible to pre-select active and reboot?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

1. I have three Windows 10 installations on separate drives on the same workstation
2. Let's say I boot into Windows install #1
3. Next, I would like to boot into windows #2

Is there a way to "pre-select" Windows #2 as the active Windows installation after I reboot - WITHOUT having to press F8 to select boot device from BIOS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

with easybcd in utilities there is ireboot which allows to define on which OS the PC will restart

and maybe also simply with msconfig
search>cmd>msconfig

Comment: ireboot only allows you to choose from Windows on the same hard drive (i.e. partitions). it does not see installations on second or third drives.

Comment: It does if they are listed in the bcd store.